# Live COVID data dashboard using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I'm intended to build a live and interactive **COVID-19 dashboard** using the **John Hopkins GitHub** repo data. I'm newbie to **Tableau**. If there is any way to connect the data and auto refresh let me know. It mean a lot to me.

GitHub repo : https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data

Comment: What's your question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to select the files that you want to use in your dashboard and find the URL of raw files on GitHub.

For example, the GitHub page URL *https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv* will become *https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv*

Now that you have the URL of raw files just follow [this guide](https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/creator_connect.htm).

Comment: Hey first of all Thank you for your time. I'm using Tableau desktop how to connect this link through which connector and how to keep the data refreshed at certain intervals to keep the fresh data. Since this is my first project on Tableau I'm struggling a bit